# Assignments in my linked list doesn't work

Tags: c, list, insert, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list that inserts an item only if it's not already present in the list. If the item is present, `ent_exists` returns a pointer to that item.

```
typedef struct nodo_ent{
  struct nodo_ent *next;
  char *ent;
}nodo_ent;

nodo_ent *head;
nodo_ent *tail;
head = NULL;
tail = NULL;

nodo_ent *ent_exists(char *ent)
{
  if (head == NULL)
 {
   return NULL;
 }
 else
 {
   nodo_ent *cursor;
   cursor = head;
   while (cursor != tail)
   {
     if (strcmp(cursor->ent, ent) == 0);
     {
       return cursor;
     }
     cursor = cursor->next;
   }
   if (strcmp(tail->ent, ent) == 0);
   {
     return tail;
   }
   return NULL;
 }
}

void addent(char *ent)
{
  if (ent_exists(ent) != NULL)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    nodo_ent nodo = {NULL, ent};
    nodo_ent *ptr;
    ptr = (nodo_ent*)malloc(sizeof(nodo_ent));
    ptr = &nodo;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
      head = ptr;
      tail = ptr;
    }
    else
    {
      tail->next = ptr;
      tail = ptr;
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

After the first call of "addent", both "head" and "tail" point to the address of the added node, but when I call it a second time and try to access tail->ent (in ent_exists), valgrind says it's uninitialised

Comment: This code snippet  nodo_ent *head;
nodo_ent *tail;
head = NULL;
tail = NULL; will not compile if it is present in the global namespace

Comment: `ptr = &nodo;` immediately overwrites the pointer to the memory allocated.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that's intended? I want a new pointer, pointing to new data, so that should get me what I want, I think. Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: What I mean is that `ptr = malloc(sizeof(nodo_ent)); ptr = &nodo;` ignores the memory allocation (since you now don't know what the pointer was), and also creates a memory leak for the same reason (the memory is not used and cannot be `free`d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Weather Vane points out,

```
nodo_ent nodo = {NULL, ent};
nodo_ent *ptr;
ptr = (nodo_ent*)malloc(sizeof(nodo_ent));
ptr = &nodo;
```

this sequence allocates memory, then overwrites the pointer to this allocated memory with the address of the local variable `nodo`.

Then you work on this local variable, but when the function returns, that local variable doesn't exist anymore and your list is corrupted.

You have it all there, just use:

```
nodo_ent *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(nodo_ent));
```

(and don't cast the result of malloc. A pointer to `void`, which malloc returns, is compatible with any pointer.)

Answer (score 0):

For starters if this code snippet

```
nodo_ent *head;
nodo_ent *tail;
head = NULL;
tail = NULL;
```

is in the global namespace then the code will not compile.

The function `ent_exists` is too complicated.

It can be implemented much simpler.

```
nodo_ent * ent_exists( const char *ent )
{
    nodo_ent *cursor = head;

    while ( cursor != NULL && strcmp( cursor->ent, ent ) != 0 )
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return cursor;  
}
```

The function `addent` should have the return type int that to report whether inserting of a new node was successful.

This code snippet

```
nodo_ent nodo = {NULL, ent};
nodo_ent *ptr;
ptr = (nodo_ent*)malloc(sizeof(nodo_ent));
ptr = &nodo;
```

does not make sense and moreover there is a memory leak.

You have to make a copy of the string that is passed as an argument. Otherwise in general the program will have undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the functions can be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct nodo_ent{
  struct nodo_ent *next;
  char *ent;
}nodo_ent;

nodo_ent *head = NULL;
nodo_ent *tail = NULL;

nodo_ent * ent_exists( const char *ent )
{
    nodo_ent *cursor = head;

    while ( cursor != NULL && strcmp( cursor->ent, ent ) != 0 )
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return cursor;  
}

int addent( const char *ent )
{
    nodo_ent *target_nodo = ent_exists( ent );

    int success = target_nodo == NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        target_nodo = malloc( sizeof( nodo_ent ) );
        success = target_nodo != NULL;
    }

    if ( success )
    {
        char *s = malloc( strlen( ent ) + 1 );

        success = s != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( s, ent );
            target_nodo->ent = s;
            target_nodo->next = NULL;
        }           
        else 
        {
            free( target_nodo );
        }           
    }

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( head == NULL )
        {
            head = tail = target_nodo;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = tail->next = target_nodo;
        }
    }       

    return success;
}

void output()
{
    for ( nodo_ent *cursor = head; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->next )
    {
        printf( "%s ", cursor->ent );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *ent;

    ent = "Hello";
    addent( ent );

    ent = "Jack";
    addent( ent );

    output();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello Jack
```